# else condition is never reached

Tags: php, mysql

When I create three conditions inside while, but only two are visible.

```
<?php 
 $ga= mysql_query("Select * from galeri");
 while ($v=mysql_fetch_object($ga)) { 

 if ($v->video==NULL){ ?> 
 <a href="images/galeri/<?php echo $v->foto?>" data-caption="<?php echo $v->judul?> - <?php echo tgl($v->tgl) ?>" data-fit="cover"  data-thumb = "images/galeri/<?php echo $v->foto?>"></a>
 <?php  } 

 else if ($v->foto==NULL AND $v->linkfoto==NULL) { ?>
 <a href="<?php echo $v->video ?>"  data-fit="cover" data-caption="<?php echo $v->judul?> - <?php echo tgl($v->tgl) ?>"  ><?php echo $v->judul?> - <?php echo tgl($v->tgl) ?></a>

 <?php  } else  { ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $v->linkfoto?>" data-caption="<?php echo $v->judul?> - <?php echo tgl($v->tgl) ?>" data-fit="cover"   data-thumb = "<?php echo $v->linkfoto?>">
<?php } }?>
```

[image: galeri Table]

You can see the field "linkfoto" contains 1 in the image above

Why conditions three `else` no appear?

Comment: Why do you use so many `<?php` and `?>` tags? Use echo instead

Comment: Or even better than `echo`: [`printf()`](http://php.net/printf)

Comment: why not? because your other conditions are always satisfied...

Comment: @user3749630 since you accepted an answer, the system already recognizes this question as solved - no need to edit the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the row `video` is empty as well, so the first check `$v->video==NULL` will probably be true and the `else` will never be reached.

To resolve this I suggest using `if` to check if a value is set on the variable you wish to use - not check if all other variables aren't set.

```
if ($v->foto != NULL) {
    printf('<a href="images/galeri/%s" data-caption="%s - %s" data-fit="cover"  data-thumb = "images/galeri/%s"></a>',
        $v->foto, $v->judul, tgl($v->tgl), $v->foto);
} elseif ($v->video != NULL) {
    //etc
} else {

}
```

This has the advantage that if you wish to edit your code in the future, you know which variables you can use inside the `if` - because you checked that they are set!

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring other basic formatting structures or other potential problems with the code, the line that says

```
else if ($v->foto=NULL && $v->linkfoto==NULL) { ?>
```

needs a second `=` sign. You're assigning `NULL` to `$v->foto` by using a single equal sign.

Correction should be:

```
else if ($v->foto == NULL && $v->linkfoto == NULL) { ?>
```

Comment: Show a `var_dump($v)` for me after the `if` statements. Please add it in an edit to your question. Also check my latest edit because you were also using `AND` instead of `&&`

Comment: @user3749630 Check my answer - the `else` is probably never reached because one of the other conditions is true

Comment: @kingkero Which is beyond the scope of my answer of course. That's dependent on the values in his table which he hasn't provided.

Comment: @kingkero Ah didn't see it. Made an edit to OP's question so it actually shows up. Also upvoted you, because it does in fact solve the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing an assignment in the else if condition, I'm guessing it should be a comparison, do:

```
$v->foto == NULL
```

instead of:

```
$v->foto = NULL
```